# Adding x-axis and y-axis to barchart in gRaphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael

I want to create a barchart using the [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) javascript library. Does gRaphael support labeled axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some axis although without labels in this [example](http://g.raphaeljs.com/linechart.html). I think you can add text to a desired position using Raphael function [text()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#text).

```
var t = paper.text(50, 50, "X Label");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could work with the axis class as well for this :

```
            var chart = r.g.barchart(50,15,gW,167,  [ this.chart.Value ], { }).hover(fin, fout);
            var aX = chart.bars[0][0].x;
            var aW = chart.bars[0][chart.bars[0].length -1].x - aX;
            var axis = r.g.axis(aX,180,aW ,null,null,this.chart.Labels.length - 1  ,2, this.chart.Labels , "|", 0);
            axis.text.attr({font:"12px Arial", "font-weight": "regular", "fill": "#FFFFFF"});
```

Answer (score 2):

[I am aware that this question is old, but here is my solution -]

I did not manage to use the r.g.axis, but I used the aX -

```
  var x, y = 250;
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++) {
    x = chart.bars[0][i].x;
    r.text(x, y, "[" + i + "]").attr(txtattr);
  }
```

Comment: +1 This is the only way I've been able to get labels to work. Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

and for the Y-axis, I added another bar, with the steps I want to mark.
I guess you can set its color to "transparent".

```
var myArrY = new Array ();                    // original values                     
// TODO: fill its values as before . . .

var myArrY_steps = new Array(0, 10, 20, 30);  // the steps I want to mark

var myData = new Array ();                     
 myData[0] = myArrY;
 myData[1] = myArrY_steps;   
 var chart = r.barchart(10, 10, 600, 300, myData, 0, {type: "sharp"});
. . . 
 var x = 10;
 var y;
 for (i = 0; i < myArrY_steps.length; i++) {
   // Note: In this loop I use chart.bars[1], the steps array!
   y = chart.bars[1][i].y;                    // calculated by gRaphael !
   r.text(x, y, chart.bars[1][i].value).attr(txtAttr);  
 }
```